# Mysql : select from five different table where matching only one column based on a date or between dates

Tags: mysql, database, date

I have five tables namely table1,table2,table3,table4 and table5.
All five are different tables. All tables have auto increment id.
One column present in all the tables with different names like 'thor_id','iron_id','wonder_id','hulk_id' and 'spider_id'(not auto increment id).
All 4 tables have date(only date) column. One table has datetime(2017-09-06 09:09:09 - not duplicate) and it has duplicate *id(which is also required).

I want to retrieve data from all the five tables based on *id and for a particular date or between 2 dates. So the resultset should be like
For one date

```
|date      | t1.id | t1.date   | t1.amt | t2.id |t2.date |t2.amt |t3.id | t3.date  | t3.amt | t4.id | t4.date | t4.amt |t5.id | t5.date  |t5.amt |
|----------|-------|-----------|--------|-------|--------|-------|------|----------|--------|-------|---------|--------|------|----------|-------|
|2017-09-06|  2341 |2017-09-06 | 10000  | null  | null   |null   |2341  |2017-09-06| 100000 | null  |  null   | null   | 2341 |2017-09-06|200000 |
```

Between two dates

```
|date       | t1.id | t1.date   | t1.amt | t2.id |t2.date    |t2.amt |t3.id | t3.date  | t3.amt | t4.id | t4.date  | t4.amt |t5.id | t5.date  |t5.amt |
|-----------|-------|-----------|--------|-------|-----------|-------|------|----------|--------|-------|----------|--------|------|----------|-------|
|2017-09-06 |  2341 |2017-09-06 | 10000  | null  | null      |null   |2341  |2017-09-06| 100000 | null  |  null    | null   | 2341 |2017-09-06|200000 |
|2017-09-07 |  2341 |2017-09-07 | 90000  | null  | null      |null   |2341  |2017-09-07| 300000 | 2341  |2017-09-07| 1000   | 2341 |2017-09-07|500000 |
|2017-09-09 |  null |null       | null   | 2341  | 2017-09-09|200000 |2341  |2017-09-07| 300000 | null  |  null    | null   | 2341 |2017-09-07|500000 |
```

1.I have tried with two tables for a date

```
select t1_date,t1_id,t1_amt,t2_date,t2_id,t_amt from t1 inner join t2 where date(t2_date)='2017-09-06' and t2_id='9106' and t1_date='2017-09-06' and t1_id='9106';
```

2.I have tried with the same two tables to retrieve data between two dates

```
select t1_date,t1_id,t1_load_amt,t2_date,t2_id,t_total from t1 inner join t2 where date(t2_date) between '2017-09-06' and '2017-09-30' and t2_id='9106' and t1_date between '2017-09-06' and '2017-09-30' and t1_id='9106';
```

No.1 gives the expected output but if i add three other tables the result set is empty.
N0.2 duplicate rows with records are created instead of null.
Am not much familiar with sql, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your description is not clear. Please read & act on [mcve]. Show DDL etc etc. Please use enough sentences & words to refer to things clearly & say what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: My bad, guess I missed the ID part.

If that's the case, then wouldn't my initial solution a much better answer?

```
SELECT 't1' AS in_table, t1.id AS id, t1.datetime, t1.amt
FROM tb1 t1 WHERE t1.id = 2341 AND t1.datetime BETWEEN '2017-09-06' AND '2017-09-09'
UNION ALL
SELECT 't2' AS in_table, t2.id AS id, t2.datetime, t2.amt
FROM tb2 t2 WHERE t2.id = 2341 AND t2.datetime BETWEEN '2017-09-06' AND '2017-09-09'
UNION ALL
SELECT 't3' AS in_table, t3.id AS id, t3.datetime, t3.amt
FROM tb3 t3 WHERE t3.id = 2341 AND t3.datetime BETWEEN '2017-09-06' AND '2017-09-09'
UNION ALL
SELECT 't4' AS in_table, t4.id AS id, t4.datetime, t4.amt
FROM tb4 t4 WHERE t4.id = 2341 AND t4.datetime BETWEEN '2017-09-06' AND '2017-09-09'
UNION ALL
SELECT 't5' AS in_table, t5.id AS id, t5.datetime, t5.amt
FROM tb5 t5 WHERE t5.id = 2341 AND t5.datetime BETWEEN '2017-09-06' AND '2017-09-09'
```

*----------------------- Old Edits Below -----------------------*

**EDIT: JUST BE WARNED, THIS IS ONE UGLY MESS AND WITH A VERY UGLY HACK**

First of all, the sample result: http://rextester.com/NFP12823

Basically, I took advantages of the power of FULL OUTER JOIN, and made something like this.

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.datetime, tbl.datetime_index) AS datetime_index, t1.id as t1_id, t1.datetime as t1_datetime, t1.amt as t1_amt, tbl.t2_id as t2_id, tbl.t2_datetime as t2_datetime, tbl.t2_amt as t2_amt, tbl.t3_id as t3_id, tbl.t3_datetime as t3_datetime, tbl.t3_amt as t3_amt, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
FROM tb1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT COALESCE(t2.datetime, tbl.datetime_index) AS datetime_index, t2.id as t2_id, t2.datetime as t2_datetime, t2.amt as t2_amt, tbl.t3_id as t3_id, tbl.t3_datetime as t3_datetime, tbl.t3_amt as t3_amt, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
    FROM tb2 t2
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT COALESCE(t3.datetime, tbl.datetime_index) AS datetime_index, t3.id as t3_id, t3.datetime as t3_datetime, t3.amt as t3_amt, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
        FROM tb3 t3
        FULL OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT COALESCE(t4.datetime, t5.datetime) AS datetime_index, t4.id as t4_id, t4.datetime as t4_datetime, t4.amt as t4_amt, t5.id as t5_id, t5.datetime as t5_datetime, t5.amt as t5_amt
            FROM tb4 t4
            FULL OUTER JOIN tb5 t5
            ON t4.datetime = t5.datetime
        ) tbl
        ON t3.datetime = tbl.datetime_index
    ) tbl
    ON t2.datetime = tbl.datetime_index
)tbl
ON t1.datetime = tbl.datetime_index
```

So starting from the center, I joined t4 and t5, and since your primary goal is to search base on time, so I created a common index datetime_index. Because on join will either return matched date or null (if not match), so by using coalesce, it'll return the first non-null, so it'd either be t4's date, or t5's date. By repeating this process for 3 more times, each on top of the previous generated table, voila, you get the full final table like that one you want.

**Note:** FULL OUTER JOIN is not supported on MySQL, you might need to look around for another hack to solve this, or just use another SQL server (I used PostgreSQL).

**EDIT2: Here's MySQL Equivalent Version** - http://rextester.com/FKMS97691

```
SELECT COALESCE(tbl.t1_datetime, tbl.datetime_index) AS datetime_index, tbl.t1_id as t1_id, tbl.t1_datetime as t1_datetime, tbl.t1_amt as t1_amt,tbl.t2_id as t2_id, tbl.t2_datetime as t2_datetime, tbl.t2_amt as t2_amt, tbl.t3_id as t3_id, tbl.t3_datetime as t3_datetime, tbl.t3_amt as t3_amt, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
FROM (SELECT tmptbl.datetime_index, t1.id as t1_id, t1.datetime as t1_datetime, t1.amt as t1_amt,tmptbl.t2_id as t2_id, tmptbl.t2_datetime as t2_datetime, tmptbl.t2_amt as t2_amt, tmptbl.t3_id as t3_id, tmptbl.t3_datetime as t3_datetime, tmptbl.t3_amt as t3_amt, tmptbl.t4_id as t4_id, tmptbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tmptbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tmptbl.t5_id as t5_id, tmptbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tmptbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
        FROM tb1 t1 LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT COALESCE(tbl.t2_datetime, tbl.datetime_index) AS datetime_index, tbl.t2_id as t2_id, tbl.t2_datetime as t2_datetime, tbl.t2_amt as t2_amt, tbl.t3_id as t3_id, tbl.t3_datetime as t3_datetime, tbl.t3_amt as t3_amt, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
            FROM (SELECT tmptbl.datetime_index, t2.id as t2_id, t2.datetime as t2_datetime, t2.amt as t2_amt,tmptbl.t3_id as t3_id, tmptbl.t3_datetime as t3_datetime, tmptbl.t3_amt as t3_amt, tmptbl.t4_id as t4_id, tmptbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tmptbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tmptbl.t5_id as t5_id, tmptbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tmptbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                    FROM tb2 t2 LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT COALESCE(tbl.t3_datetime, tbl.datetime_index) AS datetime_index, tbl.t3_id as t3_id, tbl.t3_datetime as t3_datetime, tbl.t3_amt as t3_amt, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                        FROM (SELECT tmptbl.datetime_index, t3.id as t3_id, t3.datetime as t3_datetime, t3.amt as t3_amt, tmptbl.t4_id as t4_id, tmptbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tmptbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tmptbl.t5_id as t5_id, tmptbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tmptbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                                FROM tb3 t3 LEFT JOIN (
                                    SELECT COALESCE(tbl.t4_datetime, tbl.t5_datetime) AS datetime_index, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                                    FROM (SELECT t4.id as t4_id, t4.datetime as t4_datetime, t4.amt as t4_amt, t5.id as t5_id, t5.datetime as t5_datetime, t5.amt as t5_amt
                                            FROM tb4 t4 LEFT JOIN tb5 t5 ON t4.datetime = t5.datetime
                                           UNION
                                          SELECT t4.id as t4_id, t4.datetime as t4_datetime, t4.amt as t4_amt, t5.id as t5_id, t5.datetime as t5_datetime, t5.amt as t5_amt
                                            FROM tb4 t4 RIGHT JOIN tb5 t5 ON t4.datetime = t5.datetime) tbl
                                ) tmptbl ON t3.datetime = tmptbl.datetime_index
                               UNION
                              SELECT tmptbl.datetime_index, t3.id as t3_id, t3.datetime as t3_datetime, t3.amt as t3_amt, tmptbl.t4_id as t4_id, tmptbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tmptbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tmptbl.t5_id as t5_id, tmptbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tmptbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                                FROM tb3 t3 RIGHT JOIN (
                                    SELECT COALESCE(tbl.t4_datetime, tbl.t5_datetime) AS datetime_index, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                                    FROM (SELECT t4.id as t4_id, t4.datetime as t4_datetime, t4.amt as t4_amt, t5.id as t5_id, t5.datetime as t5_datetime, t5.amt as t5_amt
                                            FROM tb4 t4 LEFT JOIN tb5 t5 ON t4.datetime = t5.datetime
                                           UNION
                                          SELECT t4.id as t4_id, t4.datetime as t4_datetime, t4.amt as t4_amt, t5.id as t5_id, t5.datetime as t5_datetime, t5.amt as t5_amt
                                            FROM tb4 t4 RIGHT JOIN tb5 t5 ON t4.datetime = t5.datetime) tbl
                                ) tmptbl ON t3.datetime = tmptbl.datetime_index) tbl
                    ) tmptbl ON t2.datetime = tmptbl.datetime_index
                   UNION
                  SELECT tmptbl.datetime_index, t2.id as t2_id, t2.datetime as t2_datetime, t2.amt as t2_amt, tmptbl.t3_id as t3_id, tmptbl.t3_datetime as t3_datetime, tmptbl.t3_amt as t3_amt, tmptbl.t4_id as t4_id, tmptbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tmptbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tmptbl.t5_id as t5_id, tmptbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tmptbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                    FROM tb2 t2 RIGHT JOIN (
                        SELECT COALESCE(tbl.t3_datetime, tbl.datetime_index) AS datetime_index, tbl.t3_id as t3_id, tbl.t3_datetime as t3_datetime, tbl.t3_amt as t3_amt, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                        FROM (SELECT tmptbl.datetime_index, t3.id as t3_id, t3.datetime as t3_datetime, t3.amt as t3_amt, tmptbl.t4_id as t4_id, tmptbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tmptbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tmptbl.t5_id as t5_id, tmptbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tmptbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                                FROM tb3 t3 LEFT JOIN (
                                    SELECT COALESCE(tbl.t4_datetime, tbl.t5_datetime) AS datetime_index, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                                    FROM (SELECT t4.id as t4_id, t4.datetime as t4_datetime, t4.amt as t4_amt, t5.id as t5_id, t5.datetime as t5_datetime, t5.amt as t5_amt
                                            FROM tb4 t4 LEFT JOIN tb5 t5 ON t4.datetime = t5.datetime
                                           UNION
                                          SELECT t4.id as t4_id, t4.datetime as t4_datetime, t4.amt as t4_amt, t5.id as t5_id, t5.datetime as t5_datetime, t5.amt as t5_amt
                                            FROM tb4 t4 RIGHT JOIN tb5 t5 ON t4.datetime = t5.datetime) tbl
                                ) tmptbl ON t3.datetime = tmptbl.datetime_index
                               UNION
                              SELECT tmptbl.datetime_index, t3.id as t3_id, t3.datetime as t3_datetime, t3.amt as t3_amt, tmptbl.t4_id as t4_id, tmptbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tmptbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tmptbl.t5_id as t5_id, tmptbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tmptbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                                FROM tb3 t3 RIGHT JOIN (
                                    SELECT COALESCE(tbl.t4_datetime, tbl.t5_datetime) AS datetime_index, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                                    FROM (SELECT t4.id as t4_id, t4.datetime as t4_datetime, t4.amt as t4_amt, t5.id as t5_id, t5.datetime as t5_datetime, t5.amt as t5_amt
                                            FROM tb4 t4 LEFT JOIN tb5 t5 ON t4.datetime = t5.datetime
                                           UNION
                                          SELECT t4.id as t4_id, t4.datetime as t4_datetime, t4.amt as t4_amt, t5.id as t5_id, t5.datetime as t5_datetime, t5.amt as t5_amt
                                            FROM tb4 t4 RIGHT JOIN tb5 t5 ON t4.datetime = t5.datetime) tbl
                                ) tmptbl ON t3.datetime = tmptbl.datetime_index) tbl
                    ) tmptbl ON t2.datetime = tmptbl.datetime_index) tbl
        ) tmptbl ON t1.datetime = tmptbl.datetime_index
       UNION
      SELECT tmptbl.datetime_index, t1.id as t1_id, t1.datetime as t1_datetime, t1.amt as t1_amt, tmptbl.t2_id as t2_id, tmptbl.t2_datetime as t2_datetime, tmptbl.t2_amt as t2_amt, tmptbl.t3_id as t3_id, tmptbl.t3_datetime as t3_datetime, tmptbl.t3_amt as t3_amt, tmptbl.t4_id as t4_id, tmptbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tmptbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tmptbl.t5_id as t5_id, tmptbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tmptbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
        FROM tb1 t1 RIGHT JOIN (
            SELECT COALESCE(tbl.t2_datetime, tbl.datetime_index) AS datetime_index, tbl.t2_id as t2_id, tbl.t2_datetime as t2_datetime, tbl.t2_amt as t2_amt, tbl.t3_id as t3_id, tbl.t3_datetime as t3_datetime, tbl.t3_amt as t3_amt, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
            FROM (SELECT tmptbl.datetime_index, t2.id as t2_id, t2.datetime as t2_datetime, t2.amt as t2_amt,tmptbl.t3_id as t3_id, tmptbl.t3_datetime as t3_datetime, tmptbl.t3_amt as t3_amt, tmptbl.t4_id as t4_id, tmptbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tmptbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tmptbl.t5_id as t5_id, tmptbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tmptbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                    FROM tb2 t2 LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT COALESCE(tbl.t3_datetime, tbl.datetime_index) AS datetime_index, tbl.t3_id as t3_id, tbl.t3_datetime as t3_datetime, tbl.t3_amt as t3_amt, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                        FROM (SELECT tmptbl.datetime_index, t3.id as t3_id, t3.datetime as t3_datetime, t3.amt as t3_amt, tmptbl.t4_id as t4_id, tmptbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tmptbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tmptbl.t5_id as t5_id, tmptbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tmptbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                                FROM tb3 t3 LEFT JOIN (
                                    SELECT COALESCE(tbl.t4_datetime, tbl.t5_datetime) AS datetime_index, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                                    FROM (SELECT t4.id as t4_id, t4.datetime as t4_datetime, t4.amt as t4_amt, t5.id as t5_id, t5.datetime as t5_datetime, t5.amt as t5_amt
                                            FROM tb4 t4 LEFT JOIN tb5 t5 ON t4.datetime = t5.datetime
                                           UNION
                                          SELECT t4.id as t4_id, t4.datetime as t4_datetime, t4.amt as t4_amt, t5.id as t5_id, t5.datetime as t5_datetime, t5.amt as t5_amt
                                            FROM tb4 t4 RIGHT JOIN tb5 t5 ON t4.datetime = t5.datetime) tbl
                                ) tmptbl ON t3.datetime = tmptbl.datetime_index
                               UNION
                              SELECT tmptbl.datetime_index, t3.id as t3_id, t3.datetime as t3_datetime, t3.amt as t3_amt, tmptbl.t4_id as t4_id, tmptbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tmptbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tmptbl.t5_id as t5_id, tmptbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tmptbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                                FROM tb3 t3 RIGHT JOIN (
                                    SELECT COALESCE(tbl.t4_datetime, tbl.t5_datetime) AS datetime_index, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                                    FROM (SELECT t4.id as t4_id, t4.datetime as t4_datetime, t4.amt as t4_amt, t5.id as t5_id, t5.datetime as t5_datetime, t5.amt as t5_amt
                                            FROM tb4 t4 LEFT JOIN tb5 t5 ON t4.datetime = t5.datetime
                                           UNION
                                          SELECT t4.id as t4_id, t4.datetime as t4_datetime, t4.amt as t4_amt, t5.id as t5_id, t5.datetime as t5_datetime, t5.amt as t5_amt
                                            FROM tb4 t4 RIGHT JOIN tb5 t5 ON t4.datetime = t5.datetime) tbl
                                ) tmptbl ON t3.datetime = tmptbl.datetime_index) tbl
                    ) tmptbl ON t2.datetime = tmptbl.datetime_index
                   UNION
                  SELECT tmptbl.datetime_index, t2.id as t2_id, t2.datetime as t2_datetime, t2.amt as t2_amt, tmptbl.t3_id as t3_id, tmptbl.t3_datetime as t3_datetime, tmptbl.t3_amt as t3_amt, tmptbl.t4_id as t4_id, tmptbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tmptbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tmptbl.t5_id as t5_id, tmptbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tmptbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                    FROM tb2 t2 RIGHT JOIN (
                        SELECT COALESCE(tbl.t3_datetime, tbl.datetime_index) AS datetime_index, tbl.t3_id as t3_id, tbl.t3_datetime as t3_datetime, tbl.t3_amt as t3_amt, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                        FROM (SELECT tmptbl.datetime_index, t3.id as t3_id, t3.datetime as t3_datetime, t3.amt as t3_amt, tmptbl.t4_id as t4_id, tmptbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tmptbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tmptbl.t5_id as t5_id, tmptbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tmptbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                                FROM tb3 t3 LEFT JOIN (
                                    SELECT COALESCE(tbl.t4_datetime, tbl.t5_datetime) AS datetime_index, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                                    FROM (SELECT t4.id as t4_id, t4.datetime as t4_datetime, t4.amt as t4_amt, t5.id as t5_id, t5.datetime as t5_datetime, t5.amt as t5_amt
                                            FROM tb4 t4 LEFT JOIN tb5 t5 ON t4.datetime = t5.datetime
                                           UNION
                                          SELECT t4.id as t4_id, t4.datetime as t4_datetime, t4.amt as t4_amt, t5.id as t5_id, t5.datetime as t5_datetime, t5.amt as t5_amt
                                            FROM tb4 t4 RIGHT JOIN tb5 t5 ON t4.datetime = t5.datetime) tbl
                                ) tmptbl ON t3.datetime = tmptbl.datetime_index
                               UNION
                              SELECT tmptbl.datetime_index, t3.id as t3_id, t3.datetime as t3_datetime, t3.amt as t3_amt, tmptbl.t4_id as t4_id, tmptbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tmptbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tmptbl.t5_id as t5_id, tmptbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tmptbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                                FROM tb3 t3 RIGHT JOIN (
                                    SELECT COALESCE(tbl.t4_datetime, tbl.t5_datetime) AS datetime_index, tbl.t4_id as t4_id, tbl.t4_datetime as t4_datetime, tbl.t4_amt as t4_amt, tbl.t5_id as t5_id, tbl.t5_datetime as t5_datetime, tbl.t5_amt as t5_amt
                                    FROM (SELECT t4.id as t4_id, t4.datetime as t4_datetime, t4.amt as t4_amt, t5.id as t5_id, t5.datetime as t5_datetime, t5.amt as t5_amt
                                            FROM tb4 t4 LEFT JOIN tb5 t5 ON t4.datetime = t5.datetime
                                           UNION
                                          SELECT t4.id as t4_id, t4.datetime as t4_datetime, t4.amt as t4_amt, t5.id as t5_id, t5.datetime as t5_datetime, t5.amt as t5_amt
                                            FROM tb4 t4 RIGHT JOIN tb5 t5 ON t4.datetime = t5.datetime) tbl
                                ) tmptbl ON t3.datetime = tmptbl.datetime_index) tbl
                    ) tmptbl ON t2.datetime = tmptbl.datetime_index) tbl
        ) tmptbl ON t1.datetime = tmptbl.datetime_index) tbl
```

This is why I said this is one ugly mess, lol.

Comment: thank you for the reply. But is it not possible to achieve what i asked? anybody?

Comment: Actually, I think there's one more way, let me fix it

Comment: I have tried the below left join query,
"SELECT t1_date,t1_id,t1_amt,t2_date,t2_id,t2_amt,
t3_date,t3_id,t3_amt,t4_date,t4_id,t4_amt,
t5_date,t5_id,t5_amt FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1_id = t2_id AND t2_date = date(t1_date)
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1_id = t3_id AND t3_date = date(t1_date)
LEFT JOIN t4 ON t1_id = t4_id AND t4_date = date(t1_date)
LEFT JOIN t5 ON t1_id = t5_id AND date(t5_date) = date(t1_date)
 WHERE date(t1_date) between '2017-09-06' and '2017-09-30'
 and t1_id='4490' ORDER BY t1_id;"

Comment: Using join query by keeping t1 as constant isn't correct

Comment: There, now give that a try.

Comment: t1_id='XXXX' isn't put as a condition , thanks, let me try to use it to get that result based on t1_id='XXXX' too.

Comment: Oh, I missed the ID is a condition as well part, however, if that's the case, why is my initial solution not matching what you want?

Comment: The first solution u have given is correct in the other way, to get the output like the table above i need to put extra conditions on my java code to convert that as json object to display in my jtable. Let me try with the mysql verion u provided @Willy_Sunny

Comment: i end up with your first solution and constructed the object as i expected using the simple union all query. As mysql not supported full outer join, the query takes considerable time to return the results. Good effort willy. +1. thanks.